# Com usar condições dentro de um método em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

**Desde já peço perdão por algum tipo de erro na criação da pergunta, estou disposto a receber ajuda**

Tenho um login usando classes que após efetuar o login do usuário, que está salvo no BD, após ser feito o login o nível do usuário logado é verificado pois a 3 níveis de privilégios no programa q faço

1. Adminstrador
2. Professor
3. Aluno

Quero limitar alguns desses usuários a usar somente algumas funções. Mas o programa somente executa  está linha.

```
public function Menu($nome, $nivel) #CRIAÇAO DOS MENUS DE ACORDO COM O NIVEL DO USUARIO.
    {


if($nivel=2){
        echo "<html lang='pt-br'>
    <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>Página inicial</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />  
    </head>
    <body >
    <div class='menu-container'>
    <ul class='menu clearfix'>
       <li><a href='?inicio'>Início</a></li>
        <li><a href='?disciplinas'>Disciplinas</a>
        ".
                    "
    </li>
    <li><a href='?salas'>Salas</a></li>

    <li><a href='?usuarios'>Usuários</a></li>

    <li><a href='?perfil'>$nome</a></li>
    <li><a href='?sair'>Sair</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>";
        }
```

Comment: `$nivel=2` é um atribuição dentro do if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua o operador `=` por `==`, dentro do `if`.

```
...
if ($nivel == 2) {
...
```

Comment: Depois em algumas alterações no $_SESSION q estava usando e com a SUA dica, consegui. Agredeço meu caro.